# I was refused a Schengen tourist Visa , so how should I reapply?

Tags: visas, germany, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I was refused a Schengen tourist Visa based on the following two reasons

1. The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose
   and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable
2. Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the
   expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

Refusal received on: 3/7/17
Travel date: 12/8/17
Planned date to reapply: Immediately

Here are the highlights of my application which I find suspicious for the rejection.

- •    I am travelling with a friend and has mentioned the same in the covering letter
- •    We applied for German Visa through Chennai VFS
- •    My friend has mentioned the that he’s travelling with me in his covering letter
- •    We both had mentioned that we’re meeting a common Indian friend in Germany who’s working for a German company, we gave his passport copy along with both of our applications. We also mentioned that he would accompany us on the trip
- •    We both booked real tickets, round trip from Chennai to Munich and produced the same along with applications
- •    Hotel bookings for the entire stay were done in my friend’s name at booking.com and I mentioned in my covering letter that booking is in his name
- •    We both had bank balance of around Rs. 200,000 and submitted the bank statement
- •    I am a proprietor of a company and he works for a company

Here are my Questions

- •    Should I not mention my friend’s name whom I am travelling with in the covering letter even though if I am traveling with him?
- •    Should I change the country of days spent more and apply though another Schengen state?
- •    Should I not mention our common Indian German friend in the covering letter?
- •    Should we do separate hotel bookings in which I get my name on the booking and he gets his own?
- •    Shall I re apply immediately?
- Shall we change the itinerary, whole plan and apply again? is it advisable?

Answer (score 3):

The reasons in the refusal mean that Germany does not *trust* you to be a genuine tourist. That is not a little thing which can be fixed with a new application. You have to look at your circumstances and explain why you would return to India.

- Any new application has to take your current circumstances and your previous application into account. They will see the data from the old application, and differences must be explained.
- The bank *balance* is not the most important part. What you need is a transparent and sufficient cash flow. ([This one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) answers in an UK context, but the principle applies.)
- It might be helpful if your friend would sign a *Verpflichtungserklärung*. That is much more than just an invitation letter, it promises that your friend will reimburse the German state if you overstay.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I checked with my guy.. He's not supposed to sign the Erklärung. Only permanent residents can do he said.. Is there any other option to get this done.. ??

Comment: @CrossRajan Are you sure about the *permanent* residency? The page https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/120691/ (for Berlin) states that your friend needs a "Aufenthaltserlaubnis", "Niederlassungserlaubnis", or "Aufenthaltstitel" - If your friend is working in Germany for more than 3 months (in a year), she/he should have one of these. Also, he/she needs to be registered as a resident in the city he is currently living in and needs to apply there. As the latter is required by law for stays >3 month, that also should not be a show-stopper.

Comment: Thank you, I conveyed this to my friend ! He's figuring it out !